# How can I write a Zend Framework App that serves requests directly (maps URLs to files)?

Tags: php, zend-framework3, psr-7

Background:  I have a legacy app that serves files as-is.  That is, i.e. when I go to `http://server/subfolder/my_index.php?value=x` it goes into `subfolder` on the file system and serves a file called `my_index.php` and passes it the URL parameters and returns a response.

I want to move onto ZF3 stack, and routing there is different.   I want to retain ZF routing model for new modules on ZF3, but also be able to use the legacy app as-is, since rewriting that app is prohibitive.

Is there a way to do so?

Not sure if it is the way to do it but I looked into the Middleware layer here:

- https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-mvc/middleware/ and
- https://zendframework.github.io/zend-diactoros/usage/

I am not clear on how to use them and if they will help me.

For example, I set up this class and not sure what to do next.

```
namespace Application\Middleware;

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Interop\Http\ServerMiddleware\MiddlewareInterface;
use Interop\Http\ServerMiddleware\DelegateInterface;
use Zend\Http\Response;

class IndexMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{

    public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, DelegateInterface $delegate)
    {
        $response = new \Zend\Diactoros\Response();
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at what your `.htaccess` or your config Nginx maybe, you would have something like that in a ZF3 project:

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting or installed the project in a subdirectory,
# the base path will be prepended to allow proper resolution of
# the index.php file; it will work in non-aliased environments
# as well, providing a safe, one-size fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

If you read the comments, you can see that files and directory are served as is if they exist.

Comment: I see..  I will try to move my legacy file folder structure into the `./public` folder and see if that works

Comment: it did work (I put ZF3 into main folder). I did have thoughts moving legacy files into `public` before but never tried it until now.  But something was off, like when file was not found I think it was trying to go through ZF3 routing and that slowed things down. Maybe.

Comment: I went with the approach of placing ZF3 into a subfolder instead.  That is, my legacy app is untouched, a new folder is added (I called it `zf`).  It worked.  Then I moved it all one folder up to where ZF3's config, vendor, and other folders ended up being in the main DOCUMENT_ROOT.  It seems to work.  I call `http://host/whatever.php` for main app and I call `http://host/public/` for ZF3.  It seems like now I can have the best of both words - legacy and ZF3 and all on the same repo (as I wanted). I bet I can call one from the other as well.

Comment: also reason I installed it into subfolder first was to isolate ZF3, and because I have my own config, vendor folders already.  I had to edit `composer.json` slightly to merge the two worlds together

Comment: Can someone post an example for a virtual host file for a zf3 project with nginx?

Comment: the question has already been covered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731555/how-to-make-zend-framework-2-work-with-nginx - Anything that's not working for you cwhisperer?